# What is the best way to use a 3 flange(alcove) shower base in a corner setup?

Tags: shower

I am having a hard time finding a quality shower base for a reasonable price.  I had to settle for [a base](https://www.americanstandard.ca/-/media/sites/asus/files/product-instruction-manuals/shower-bases/2018/installationinstructions-solid-surface-shower-bases.pdf?la=en-CA) that is designed for an alcove installation.

Could there be any issues if I am installing the glass like in the picture?

Please note that the close to the viewer corner shows how the flange shows up behind the shower glass. Since I have about 3-4 inches I could build  a small box and tile it and then put the shower on top of it.

The problem that I am seeing here is in the left side corner near the wall.
The flange on the right side could create an unwanted space there.

[image]

To addres @isherwood's comment with the base possibly open on one the sides where the flanges are here is a cross section from their documentation
I also think that the manufacturer would risk to build structural weakness if the shower pane does not have a full edge side (ie it would be hollow on the sides as the drop in tubs are) This is from their manual
[image]

And here is the right side view of the base from the US manual. Hmm that might be a section. However based on the cross section I do not see how they can leave that in the air
[image]

The description of my shower says solid surface -not sure what that means but I don't think it is like this one
[image]

Comment: Have you talked to a local plumbing supply house? It seems like you're making problems for yourself that shouldn't exist. The main problem will be that the outer end face of such a pan won't be finished.

Comment: @isherwood  Yes I am in contact with plumbing stores to supply the above. I guess what you are saying is that the right side might not have a solid vertical piece and it will be open like the alcove bath tubs but I don't think it is like that. Good question though I will check with the suppliers
How about the other things that I am asking about ?